# Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional components. on VS Code

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, sdk

Getting error while installing in the new laptop (Windows 10) in vs code 
✓ Java SDK 
✓ Android SDK 
✓ Flutter SDK 
✓ ADB Driver 
✓ Set Env Path for all SDK 
✓ run `flutter config --android-sdk <path>` 
after that it's showing my device but when I am trying to run `flutter run`
It's showing no device found. I searched for other solutions but didn't help me.

**Any solution?** 
Error Screenshot [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aJ6QkwW2EhgZBc02Sddm1MXvL-b1ig9y/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: try running `flutter doctor` it will display a report of the status of your Flutter installation.

Comment: `flutter doctor` after running this command. I get Unable to locate Android SDK and No Valid Android SDK Platform. But I set the Android SDK root folder path to env

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

Install Android API Level 29 from Android SDK Manager. Then install Android Licenses from Android SDK Manager. Then run `flutter doctor -v` for checking proper installation.

Another solution which I have found. Many devs are trying to install android studio first then download all the SDK after that uninstall the android studio.

I hope you will get your proper solution from here.
[github issue solved](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22649#issuecomment-520472515)